# Please help me with table/nested JOIN optimization: Way too slow!

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, optimization, join

I have about 250 tables in my database, each with exactly 439340 rows.

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE data.b50d1 ;
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE `b50d1` (
      `pTime` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `Slope` double NOT NULL,
      `STD` double NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`pTime`),
      KEY `Slope` (`Slope`) USING BTREE
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 MIN_ROWS=43940 MAX_ROWS=43940 PACK_KEYS=1 ROW_FORMAT=FIXED |
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, there are three columns in each table:

- **pTime**: POSIX timestamp. This column (and all of its values) is exactly the same in each table. This is my `PRIMARY KEY`
- **Slope**
- **STD**

The columns Slope and STD have 'signed double' values that differ from row-to-row and from table-to-table.

Here is a small sample from one of the tables:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM data.b50d1 limit 10;
+------------+------------+-------------+
| pTime      | Slope      | STD         |
+------------+------------+-------------+
| 1104537600 | 6.38733032 | -1.13387667 |
| 1104537900 | 5.58733032 | -0.93810617 |
| 1104538200 | 5.30135747 | -0.51912757 |
| 1104538500 |  5.4678733 | -0.54460575 |
| 1104538800 | 5.58190045 | -0.46369055 |
| 1104539100 | 5.50226244 | -0.46712018 |
| 1104714000 | 5.31221719 | -0.25210485 |
| 1104714300 | 4.72941176 |  0.00321249 |
| 1104714600 | 5.19638009 |  0.64116376 |
| 1104714900 | 5.12941176 |  0.39599099 |
+------------+------------+-------------+
```

Using these tables I run a stored procedure. This procedure consists of the following steps:

STEP 1) `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` MainList...

STEP 2) `INSERT` the results of a `SELECT` statement into the table. The resulting dataset is a filtered composite of the original tables.

STEP 3) `SELECT` statement with nested `JOIN`s iterates through each MainList.STD value of the `TEMPORARY` table (MainList), and returns the first row *from one of the original tables* that matches certain specified conditions (example below).

STEP 4) `JOIN` the results to MainList and output them to the user.

The following is the procedure itself:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetTimeList`(t1 varchar(7),t2 varchar(7),t3 varchar(7),inp1 float,inp2 float,inp3 float,inp4 float,inp5 float,inp6 float,inp7 float,inp8 float,inp9 float,inp10 float)
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MainList;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE MainList(
  `pTime` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `STD` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pTime`),
    KEY (`STD`) USING BTREE
    ) ENGINE = MEMORY;  

SET @s = CONCAT('INSERT INTO MainList(pTime,STD)  SELECT DISTINCT t1.pTime, t1.STD FROM ',t1,' AS t1 JOIN (',t2,' as t2 ,',t3,' as t3 )',
' ON (( t1.Slope >= ', inp1,
' AND t1.Slope <= ', inp2,
' AND t1.STD  >= ', inp3,
' AND t1.STD  <= ', inp4,
' AND t2.Slope  >= ', inp5,
' AND t2.Slope  <= ', inp6,
' AND t3.Slope  >= ', inp7,
' AND t3.Slope  <= ', inp8,
' ) OR ( t1.Slope <= ', 0-inp1,
' AND t1.Slope >= ', 0-inp2,
' AND t1.STD  <= ', 0-inp3,
' AND t1.STD  >= ', 0-inp4,
' AND t2.Slope  <= ', 0-inp5,
' AND t2.Slope  >= ', 0-inp6,
' AND t3.Slope  <= ', 0-inp7,
' AND t3.Slope  >= ', 0-inp8,
' ) ) AND ((t1.Slope < 0 XOR t1.STD < 0) AND t1.pTime = t2.pTime AND t2.pTime = t3.pTime AND t1.pTime >= ', inp9,
' AND t1.pTime <= ', inp10,' ) ORDER BY t1.pTime'
);

PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;

SET @q= CONCAT('SELECT m.pTime as OpenTime, CASE WHEN m.STD < 0 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END As Type, mu.pTime As CloseTime from MainList m LEFT JOIN ',t1,' mu ON mu.pTime = ( SELECT DISTINCT md.pTime FROM ',t1,' md WHERE md.pTime>m.pTime',' AND md.pTime <= ', inp10,
                            ' AND SIGN (md.STD)!= SIGN (m.STD) AND ABS(md.STD) >= ABS(m.STD) ORDER BY md.pTime LIMIT 1 )');


PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
DROP TABLE MainList;
END
```

For ease of testing I have broken up the above procedure into two individual queries. Here are those queries accompanied by '**EXPLAIN EXTENDED**' statements (the temp table was generated beforehand) :

### **FIRST QUERY**

---

```
INSERT INTO MainList(pTime,STD)
SELECT
  t1.pTime,
  t1.STD
 FROM
  b50d1 AS t1
 JOIN(b75d1 AS t2, b100d1 AS t3)ON(
  (
          t1.Slope >= 2.3169
          AND t1.Slope <= 7.0031
          AND t1.STD >= - 2.068
          AND t1.STD <= - 0.972
          AND t2.Slope >= 0.3179
          AND t2.Slope <= 5.7221
          AND t3.Slope >= 2.6466
          AND t3.Slope <= 35.7534
  )
  OR(
          t1.Slope <= - 2.3169
          AND t1.Slope >= - 7.0031
          AND t1.STD <= 2.068
          AND t1.STD >= 0.972
          AND t2.Slope <= - 0.3179
          AND t2.Slope >= - 5.7221
          AND t3.Slope <= - 2.6466
          AND t3.Slope >= - 35.7534
  )
 )
 AND(
  (t1.Slope < 0 XOR t1.STD < 0)
  AND t1.pTime = t2.pTime
  AND t2.pTime = t3.pTime
  AND t1.pTime >= 1104710000
  AND t1.pTime <= 1367700000
 )
 ORDER BY
  t1.pTime;
```

**EXPLAIN EXTENDED:**

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------+--------+----------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref           | rows   | filtered | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------+--------+----------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | ALL    | PRIMARY,Slope | NULL    | NULL    | NULL          | 439340 |    25.79 | Using where; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,Slope | PRIMARY | 4       | data.t1.pTime |      1 |   100.00 | Using where                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t3    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | data.t1.pTime |      1 |   100.00 | Using where                 |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------+--------+----------+-----------------------------+
```

### **SECOND QUERY**

---

```
SELECT
    m.pTime AS OpenTime,
    CASE WHEN m.STD < 0 THEN 1 ELSE - 1 END AS Type,
  mu.pTime AS CloseTime;
FROM
    MainList m
LEFT JOIN b50d1 mu ON mu.pTime =(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        md.pTime
    FROM
        b50d1 md
    WHERE
        md.pTime > m.pTime
    AND md.pTime <= 1367700000
    AND SIGN(md.STD)!= SIGN(m.STD)
    AND ABS(md.STD)>= ABS(m.STD)
    ORDER BY
        md.pTime
    LIMIT 1
);
```

**EXPLAIN EXTENDED:**

```
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | m     | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |     16 |   100.00 |             |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | mu    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | func |      1 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | md    | range  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 439338 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
```

The query works and returns the right results, but it is *orders of magnitude* slower than what I need. I recognize that the `type: ALL` statement present in both `EXPLAIN` statements indicates that my indices are likely suboptimal.

I have only used MYSQL for the past week, and I am starting to feel like I am in over my head. I would really appreciate some help.

I made a SQL file with `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements so that anyone kind enough to try to help me could create smaller versions of my tables in the"Test" database:
[slowtables.SQL](http://www.furlender.com/slowtables.SQL)

For completeness here is the my.ini settings file - perhaps it is a bottleneck?

```
[client]
pipe
socket=mysql
[mysql]
default-character-set=latin1
[mysqld]
skip-networking
enable-named-pipe
socket=mysql
basedir="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/"
datadir="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/Data/"
character-set-server=latin1
default-storage-engine=MYISAM
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
max_connections=100
query_cache_size=189M
table_cache=256
tmp_table_size=192M
key_buffer_size=594M
read_buffer_size=64K
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K
sort_buffer_size=256K
```

Comment: Is this a grad school project?

Comment: Have you tried putting an index on both STD and Slope?

Comment: @Mark: Its not a grad school project.. I am doing this for technical analysis of FOREX.

Comment: @Mark: Yeah, I tried putting an index on them both. Not much of an improvement :(

Comment: I can see that on query 1, you are testing `t1.STD < 0`, and you have no index on STD, so this forces MySQL to check every row of the table....

Comment: @Mark Eirich 
Like this?  
ALTER TABLE `b50d1` ADD INDEX `Slope` (`Slope`) USING BTREE;  
ALTER TABLE `b50d1` ADD INDEX `STD` (`STD`) USING BTREE ;  
  
I just tried that again to make sure, and it produced the exact same EXTENDED SELECT statement as before.

Comment: @Mark Eirich I meant to write "the exact same EXPLAIN EXTENDED statement.."

Comment: How slow is "way too slaw"?  What's your target for speed?

Comment: @Walter 
I would like a final result of 1000 values to take no longer than 10 seconds (preferably less than 5). 
That is how long it takes me to calculate 1000 values from scratch without the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to work with your first query sample, and all tables have ... as you mentioned ... the exact same "pTime" value, I might alter the query to the following...  I don't know for sure if the math XOR is faster than a direct multiplication of the slope * STD.  If only ONE of them can be negative, the only result WOULD be a negative as two negatives = positive (so too are two positives)...

However, I've moved the WHERE clause up-front to explicitly qualify the query time range first even before it tries to complete the joining to tables 2 and 3...

I wasn't sure about the multiplication vs the XOR call, but I'll bet that did have a factor in the longer time.  Additionally, trying to pre-emptively use an ABS() check on the slope too.  That being said, I would do it as a UNION since slope too is key on the table, utilize it as exact part of the key and NOT via an evaluated function in ABS().  I can do a UNION ALL since one criteria is checking for slope negative and the other where positive, each unique SQL will never include the other's result set.  Additionally, we can throw out the XOR check since the rest of your AND clauses are explicitly qualifying slope as opposite sign of the std.

THEN, tack on your other considerations of slope and std

```
INSERT INTO MainList(pTime,STD)
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      t1.pTime,
      t1.STD
   FROM
      b50d1 AS t1
         JOIN b75d1 AS t2
            ON t1.pTime = t2.pTime
         JOIN b100d1 AS t3
            ON t1.pTime = t3.pTime
   where 
          t1.pTime >= 1104710000
      AND t1.pTime <= 1367700000
      AND t1.Slope >= 2.3169
      AND t1.Slope <= 7.0031
      AND t1.STD >= - 2.068
      AND t1.STD <= - 0.972
      AND t2.Slope >= 0.3179
      AND t2.Slope <= 5.7221
      AND t3.Slope >= 2.6466
      AND t3.Slope <= 35.7534
   ORDER BY
      t1.pTime
UNION ALL
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      t1.pTime,
      t1.STD
   FROM
      b50d1 AS t1
         JOIN b75d1 AS t2
            ON t1.pTime = t2.pTime
         JOIN b100d1 AS t3
            ON t1.pTime = t3.pTime
   where 
          t1.pTime >= 1104710000
      AND t1.pTime <= 1367700000
      AND t1.Slope >= - 7.0031
      AND t1.Slope <= - 2.3169
      AND t1.STD >=  0.972
      AND t1.STD <=  2.068
      AND t2.Slope >= - 5.7221
      AND t2.Slope <= - 0.3179
      AND t3.Slope >= - 35.7534
      AND t3.Slope <= - 2.6466;
```

A THIRD version would be to pre-query for the qualifying entries, then continue to rest of the join... (inner, building "PQ" PreQuery resultset)

```
INSERT INTO MainList(pTime,STD)
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      pq.pTime,
      pq.STD
   FROM
      ( select
              t1.pTime,
              t1.slope,
              t1.std
           from 
              b50d1 t1
           where
                  t1.pTime >= 1104710000
              AND t1.pTime <= 1367700000
              AND (( t1.slope between 2.3169 and 7.0031
                    AND t1.std between -2.068 and -.972 )
                  OR 
                   ( t1.slope between -7.0031 and -2.3169  
                    AND t1.std between .972 and 2.068 )) ) PQ
         JOIN b75d1 AS t2
            ON p1.pTime = t2.pTime
         JOIN b100d1 AS t3
            ON p1.pTime = t3.pTime
   where 
          (     pq.slope > 0
            AND t2.Slope >= 0.3179
            AND t2.Slope <= 5.7221
            AND t3.Slope >= 2.6466
            AND t3.Slope <= 35.7534 
          )
       OR
          (     pq.slope > 0
            AND t2.Slope >= -5.7221
            AND t2.Slope <= -0.3179
            AND t3.Slope >= -35.7534 
            AND t3.Slope <= -2.6466
          )
   ORDER BY
      t1.pTime
```

Comment: @DRapp
That code looks much cleaner than mine... unfortunately it actually took a bit *longer* to execute.

Comment: @DRapp
Is it possible that my server settings configuration file is to blame? I included it at the bottom of my initial question.

Comment: @Mike Furlender, adjusted and altered options... hope it helps

Comment: @DRapp Thanks for taking the time to look through this. Unfortunately the top query is still slower than my version of it. (Mine = 0.4s, Yours = 0.7s). When I try to run the second one I get an error message: " Unknown column 't1.pTime' in 'on clause". Anyway it seems that my second query is the time consuming one.

Comment: @Mike Furlender, sorry, check the JOIN clause... When I  processed the "PreQuery" (aliased PQ), I forgot to update the JOIN / ON clauses to reflect the PQ. instead of t1.   Try that.

Comment: Hm, it is even slower yet :(

    PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    |  
    PRIMARY     | t2         | eq_ref |  
    PRIMARY     | t3         | eq_ref |
    DERIVED     | t1         | ALL    |

Comment: @DRapp I think I came up with a way to get a substantial boost in speed. In my second query, instead of checking the entire time span, I only need to check up until the pTime with an opposite "Type" value (from MainList table)

Comment: @Mike Furlender, sorry I couldn't help out with the performance.

Comment: @DRapp No problem at all. Your code really helped me better understands joins!

Answer (score 1):

I see two improvements possible here that have more to do with MySQL's optimizer (or weakness thereof). In the second query, the DISTINCT in the subquery is redundant given the LIMIT 1. A ORDER BY  LIMIT 1 query should be done by searching the index until a record matching the other criteria is found. (Do you really need a LEFT JOIN??)

In the first query, MySQL is apparently unable to optimize an OR into a UNION. However, if you do that by hand, it may choose much better plans for the two halves of the UNION query.

HTH. I can look again later.

Comment: I will try that tomorrow morning and get back to you.

Comment: You are absolutely right about the left join. That sped it up considerably. I am still looking to speed it up further though. Perhaps through partitioning?

Comment: I don't know about MySQL and partitioning (Postgresql myself). Did you look at the explain plans after changing the `SELECT X WHERE (Y OR Z)` to `SELECT X WHERE Y UNION ALL SELECT X WHERE Z`? I think I have seen here before that MySQL can't optimize `OR` disjuncts. (Some other DBs can.) So you might get two index scans instead of a table scan, big win.